# angularjs recursive template maximum call stack size error with third party objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I have a recursive template to show menu nodes like this:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
        <button  ng-if="data.nodes" ng-click="toggle(data)">o</button>       
         <span >{{data.name}}</span>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
        </ul>
    </script>

    <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my angularjs controller is like this:

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tree = [
        {
            name: "Node-1",
            layer: new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'}),
            nodes: [
                {
                    name: "Node-1 Sublayer",
                    layer: new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'}),
                    nodes:[]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    $scope.toggle = function(node){
        node.layer.visibility = !node.layer.visibility;
    };
}]);
```

`OpenLayers.Layer.WMS` is third party framework object. And my working [DEMO is like here](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/qwxrcv3g/10/).

**1-** When I add `ng-class="data.nodes"` directive with a span element in my recursive template,

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
        <button  ng-if="data.nodes" ng-click="toggle(data)">o</button>       
         <span ng-class="{'layer-name': data.nodes, 'layer-title':!data.nodes}">{{data.name}}</span>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
        </ul>
    </script>

    <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am getting an error like this:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

**2-** If I remove layers object from my `tree` subnode like this:

```
   $scope.tree = [
        {
            name: "Node-1",
            layer: new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'}),
            nodes: [
                {
                    name: "Node-1 Sublayer",
                    nodes:[]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

> it is working.

But I will add multiple sub layers under this tree. So I can not workink with this issue.

Comment: just do `!!data.nodes` here `<span ng-class="{'layer-name': !!data.nodes,`. updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwxrcv3g/11/)

Comment: why do this? what is the reason of problem?

Comment: i don't know :-) seems `ng-class` can not convert `data.nodes` to truthly or falsey value and when you do it manually - it start work. Possibly it regards to recursive templates

Comment: are you try this? this solve your problem?

Comment: Amazingly yes :) thanks. May be a bug?

Comment: you can post it as issue in angular github and link to this question :-)

Comment: for example here [angular.js/issues](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues) add new Issue

Comment: also if you try with last angular version, you can get another error: `TypeError: Illegal invocation`